# Windows 10 drive is locked by bitlocker and do not know password to login

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker, format, reinstall

I have a few old laptops with windows 10 on them. We used them previously for a few coworkers and we do not know the password to unlock them and it looks like some of them have the bitlocker encryption on the drive. These are dell and microsoft laptops. I just want to wipe them and start from scratch. The recovery image options is most ideal, but it keeps asking for the "recovery key id" which I don't have.

I do have a windows 10 installation USB that I can boot into. I was thinking of just deleting all the partitions and reinstalling window10 from scratch, but it would be best if I can just restore from a factory image with all the drivers preinstalled already.

I found a few windows 10 password crackers online, but I wasn't sure if they even work if there is bitlocker installed on the drives. Should I just wipe all the partitions and reinstall or is there a better easier way?

Comment: Do you care about whatever data is stored on those drives? If not, I'd wipe em.

Comment: what about all the default apps/drivers for the laptops? I just don't want to deal with having to download each driver manually. I have like 8 laptops I need to do this for. I don't care for any of the other information.

Comment: Don't worry; Windows 10 automatically downloads all necessary drivers. Only in very rare hardware combinations would you need to do anything. - actually, starting from scratch will give you a much faster and better system than 'fixing' the existing installations - if you even manage to get in, Bitlocker has no known 'cracks'.

Comment: @Aganju https://github.com/e-ago/bitcracker & https://www.howtogeek.com/769074/latest-intel-cpu-flaw-lets-thieves-crack-bitlocker-encryption/ & https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/12/first-commercial-tool-cracks-bitlocker/

Comment: so there's no point in downloading or buying one of those cracking tools to unlock an win10 admin account then?

Comment: No, don't waste time or money with cracking if you don't need data from the harddisk. You'll be up and running in 30 minutes with a fresh install. Note that you would need to first crack Bitlocker, and then also Windows admin password. It's two independent things.

Comment: You WILL NOT crack bitlocker and the "cracking tools" are free.  No need to pay for one.

Comment: See this>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124361/bitlocker-is-prompting-for-a-recovery-key-and-you-cannot-locate-the-key

Comment: You're also *safer* just repartitioning the disks. There is no way to know what malware and other programs have been installed. There are also tools from MS and elsewhere to deploy to multiple PC's, even of differnt models, e.g., https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831764(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any data on the system and don't care for manufacturer's bloatware included with the startup system. Just fresh install windows 10, pick advanced during install and delete all partitions. Takes less than 30 min to get a fresh system.